# SQL database performance optimization

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, performance, performance-tuning

We have a write-heavy SQL database (SQL Server 2008) and the insert speed decreases after some time. I read these similar questions: [Sql insert speed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090243/sql-insert-speed-up), [SQL: What is slowing down INSERTs if not CPU or IO?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13523/sql-what-is-slowing-down-inserts-if-not-cpu-or-io) and [Speed up INSERTs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13866/speed-up-inserts).

Also, I read [this post](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/) about how to analyze SQL Server performance which helped me to know how to find bottlenecks (for example, by querying `sys.dm_exec_requests` and `sys.dm_os_wait_stats`), but still I have difficulties in interpreting the query results and fixing the problem.

First, I started with querying the `sys.dm_exec_requests` which only returned one session id (select query) with status **"running"** (i.e., I found NO SUSPENDED SESSIONS). So, if nothing has blocked my insert, why does it become slow?

Next, I used `sys.dm_os_wait_stats` to check statistics about all wait types. The result showed that **LATCH_EX, CXPACKET** AND **PAGEIOLATCH_SH** had the most **wait_time** (694379 ms, 310364 ms and 308335 ms respectively).

Then I used `sys.dm_os_latch_stats` to find the most prevalent latch type which in my case was `ACCESS_METHODS_DATASET_PARENT`.

- First of all, I don't know how to find the query related to each session_id in the results of querying `sys.dm_exec_requests`.
- Secondly, what numbers of wait-time (in `sys.dm_os_wait_stats`) should be considered as high? And if the above mentioned numbers (results of sys.dm_os_wait_stats) are high, how can I decrease them?
- As far as I understand, `ACCESS_METHODS_DATASET_PARENT` is related to parallelism and [one of the solutions I've found](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126095/how-to-reduce-huge-cxpacket-latch-ex-access-methods-dataset-parent-wait-time) was reducing the degree of parallelism. Is that right?
- In MySQL, there are [some tunning settings](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/28/10-mysql-performance-tuning-settings-after-installation/) which could be done right after installation (e.g., increasing innodb buffer pool size), is there something similar in SQL Server?

**Some more info:**

- Using `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`, number of reads and writes are
  80336 and 70672 respectively.
- One of our most busy tables is `trans_all` (showing all payments
  transactions) with NO TRIGGERS, NO CONSTRAINTS (this is the same for
  all tables), but it has a CLUSTERED INDEX, namely, `PK_trans_all`
  consist of    the following columns: gs_id(smallint), pt_id(tinyint),
  fueling_time(datetime), purchase_type(tinyint).
- Database size is 2.6 GB and the size of `trans_all` table is 155 MB.

**UPDATE_1**

Regarding the `ACCESS_METHODS_DATASET_PARENT`, I tried the solution that I've found (i.e., changing the degree of parallelism. I changed it to 1 to make sure that query never go to parallelism), but it didn't fix the issue :| should I change it again? what is the default that I should use?

**UPDATE_2**

I just checked the size of [transaction log file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189768.aspx) for my database which is **2.4 GB** and %log space used is **98%.** Could this be the reason to slow down my inserts? Should I increase the log file size?

Also, I used [`sys.database_files`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174397.aspx) to check the file size, and the amount of empty space for my database. Result shows that filesize is **195 MB** and empty space is **0.187 MB**.

Comment: I've always found sp_WhoIsActive http://sqlblog.com/files/folders/release/tags/who+is+active/default.aspx to be excellent for a concise snapshot of whats going on without having to dig through DMV's. Where do you observe 'insert speed decreases'? Do you have a front end app? Or a data logger? If a data logger how does it report a decrease in insert speed? From your description I guess there are many frequent small record insertions from many clients rather than lots of large bulk data insertions?

Comment: My guess would be that your clustered index on many columns will be slowing things down, as you won't be inserting in the free and clear space at the end of the table, but instead inserting in already-busy pages in the middle. I would probably recommend changing the clustered index on that table to a simple incrementing ID and moving your existing index to a simple nonclustered one if necessary. But dba would be a better place to ask, I'd say...

Comment: @MattGibson the inserts are at the end of tables

Comment: Is that the exact order that your clustered index is defined in (`gs_id, pt_id, fueling_time, purchase_type`)? If so, I expect the inserts are not at the end of the tables as you have said, and you are experiencing a large number of page splits during your inserts.

Comment: Measure the fragmentation.  Is insert faster after you defragment?

Comment: @GarethD: yes, that is the exact order of clustered index. about inserts, honestly, I am not sure if they are at the end of tables (I just guessed since we don't have delete, and we have incremental id), how could I check if inserts are at the end of table?

Comment: @monomania If you have incremental ID, then making that incremental ID your clustered index instead of what you have now is the way to ensure your inserts go at the end of the table.

Comment: @monamona regarding the high wait times, how many physical data files do you have for your database?  It could be also reaching GAM/SGAM contention if you only have 1 and it is heavily accessed.  Can you list your DB file layout?  Secondly can you record the perfmon metrics of disk sec/read and disk sec/write for the drives containing the transaction log and data files?  This will tell us ultimately if there is actually a physical IO issue here or not.  If not, it might be logical.  your exclusive latch doesn't have _io at the end of it, so I suspect it's logical file contention.

Comment: For the trans log run a DBCC LOGINFO() after you USE [Database].  Please let us know how many rows are returned.  Plz check tbl fragmentation and IFI.  Server 2008 required you to enable that.  Check this and see if it is your issue.  If you want, you can try to auto size it a bit to see if it waits or not.  If it's instant, great.  If not, you have growth issues too. https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/instant-file-initialization/.  Your file size is maxed, it might have to pause transactions until it adds more disk space.  Depending on your autogrowth that can also cause physical fragmentation.

Answer (score 2):

There are many factors that could be causing this slow down of inserts as you have described.

Something that I do not see in your information is the Database / Table size that the inserts are going into.  As the table grows, the longer your inserts will take due to table size, fragmentation and writing the same data to your indexes.

The DM queries you are running have given you some good information.  I would also recommend using Brent Ozar's toolkit. [Link](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit)

I would suggest you use SP_BlitzIndex and SP_BlitzCache.  These will give you another view of what is actually happening in the database and what the insert queries you are running are doing at that time.

I would also check when the last time a DBCC CHECKDB was run and also when you last rebuilt your indexes and statistics.

Thanks for the updates, see below:

Some more info:

Not a huge amount of read/writes so I'm not too concerned.

Do you know when the last time the trans_all index was rebuilt?  If you only have one covering index and many inserts, it will take longer each time when inserting data to it if it is out of date.  Below is a query to check fragmentation on your database tables:

```
Use <Database>
GO

SELECT OBJECT_NAME(ind.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName, 
ind.name AS IndexName, indexstats.index_type_desc AS IndexType, 
indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) indexstats 
INNER JOIN sys.indexes ind  
ON ind.object_id = indexstats.object_id 
AND ind.index_id = indexstats.index_id 
WHERE indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 30 
ORDER BY indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent DESC
```

UPDATE 1:

MAX DOP settings can affect your query run time, but I can't be sure it is doing so without seeing the query you are using and then looking at the estimated plan results to see what SQL server is using.  There are two statistics to use to find out how the query is affected when adjusting the MAX DOP.

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
GO
```

Here is some information by Kendra Little over at Brent Ozar on using these to give you guidelines.

[tsql-measure-performance-improvements](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/06/tsql-measure-performance-improvements/)

and

[q-can-high-maxdop-make-a-query-slower](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/12/q-can-high-maxdop-make-a-query-slower/)

UPDATE 2:

I would recommend increasing your Log size if it is 98% full.  Either add another trans log or increase it.  You might also look at TEMP_DB and see what it is doing because SQL using that as a dumping ground for many things.

Empty space isn't really an issue unless you are out of room to grow.  It is just telling you how much room is left until the next auto grow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, do you think the problem was not related to degree of parallelism? (since I've seen `ACCESS_METHODS_DATASET_PARENT` as the result of `sys.dm_os_latch_stats`? I mean, if it was not the problem why I had to use dmv?

Answer (score 0):

If your database is being log-shipped then what could be happening is that the log is filling up with Transactions, then waiting until the next log backup before cleaning them out and making the space for new transactions to continue processing. Try reducing the gap between Log-shipping periods, or increasing the size of the log file.
There's other stuff you can do like checking index useage stats and removing unused indexes, their maintenance will create extra demand on the log.